# Help identifying furniture maker by initials

Tags: furniture

This chair was purchased used in the 1970s in NH (US).  It appears to be oak and bears the manufacturer's initials **H.U.**  Where can I look for more information about who made the chair?[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that this is answerable.  Some furniture was made by family members, others by local individuals who never enter the historical record.  Other times initials were burned by mischievous children . There may be no record of "H.U".   [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: The location of the initials is rather odd - I don't think that a manufacturer would place them in such a visible location, but rather mark it underneath. A family probably wouldn't mark on the front or the side either. Possible that an organization - such as a church or school - would want to show ownership in an easy-to-see way, so the item could be retrieved (and be less prone to borrowing),